# How do I override the entrypoint and pass Bash commands as a string?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I don't want to modify the Dockerfile.

I want to override the entrypoint and run arbitrary commands but this is not working for me:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash myimage bash -c "echo aaaa &"
```

I get `/bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file`

I want to be able to immediately start a background job before entering the container interactively- again without modifying the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When Docker launches a container, it [combines the "entrypoint" and "command" parts together into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The `docker run --entrypoint` option only takes a single "word" for the entrypoint command.

So, say you need to run `some command --with an-arg`.  You need to

1. Break this into words
2. Pass the first word as `docker run --entrypoint`, before the image name
3. Pass the remaining words as the command part, after the image name.

```sh
# some command --with an-arg
docker run \
  --entrypoint some
  image-name \
  command --with an-arg

# ls -al /
docker run --rm \
  --entrypoint /bin/ls
  image-name \
  -al /

# bash -c "echo aaaa"
docker run --rm \
  --entrypoint /bin/bash \
  image-name \
  -c 'echo aaaa'
```

This construct is kind of awkward.  If you control the image, I tend to recommend making the image's `CMD` be a complete command, and either omitting `ENTRYPOINT` or making it be a wrapper that takes a complete command as arguments (for example, a shell script that ends in `exec "$@"`).

```sh
# Hard to replace with an alternate command:
# ENTRYPOINT python3 ./manage.py runserver

# Better:
CMD python3 ./manage.py runserver
```

```sh
# Takes a complete command as arguments
# (MUST use JSON-array form)
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

# Can be overridden at runtime
# (But whatever you supply will run in a Ruby Bundler context)
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```